# Segmentation Fault and semaphores not working correctly

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, semaphore

I've been working on this assignment for school that requires me to make a program that uses 3 processes in total, and uses semaphores to count from 0 to a number specified by a argument maxnum which has to be initialized from within the main after the two children have been forked and the processes must print out the numbers in such a way that the main does numbers 0, 3, 6, the first child 1, 4, 7 and the second child 2, 5, 8. I've been having problems figuring out why my code is giving me segmentation faults when it reaches the first sem_post() command within my code. I had my code working at one point but when it ran, the order that the processes printed out the numbers was always completely random and never remotely close to right order I needed. I have been deleting the junk semaphore after failures too so that eliminates that problem. Any help in this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the printfs are just there so I know which order they post, and sorry for how messy my code may be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>


#define SEM_NAME "/test.mutex"

sem_t *sem1;
sem_t *sem2;
sem_t *sem3;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

sem1 = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 1);
if(sem1 == (void *)-1){
    perror("sem_open() failed ");
}
sem2 = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
if(sem2 == (void *)-1){
    perror("sem_open() failed ");
}
sem3 = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, 0);
if(sem3 == (void *)-1){
    perror("sem_open() failed ");
}


int *curnum;
int *maxnum;


const int segment_size = 4096;


int segment_id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, segment_size,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);


curnum = (int *) shmat(segment_id, NULL, 0);
maxnum = curnum + 1;


if(fork()){
    if(fork()){
        *maxnum = atoi(argv[1]);
        sem_wait(sem1);
        while(*curnum <= *maxnum){
            printf("%d", *curnum);
            printf(" Main \n");
            ++curnum[0];
            sem_post(sem2);
            sem_wait(sem1);
        }
        printf("Exiting Main Loop");
        sem_post(sem2);
        wait();
        shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    }
    else{
        sem_wait(sem3);
        while(*curnum <= *maxnum){
            printf("%d", *curnum);
            printf(" Child 1\n");
            ++curnum[0];
            sem_post(sem1);
            sem_wait(sem3);
        }
        printf("Exiting Child 1 Loop");
        sem_post(sem1);
    }
}
else{
    sem_wait(sem2);
    while(*curnum <= *maxnum){
        printf("%d", *curnum);
        printf(" Child 2\n");
        ++curnum[0];
        sem_post(sem3);
        sem_wait(sem2);
    }
    printf("Exiting Child 2 Loop");
    sem_post(sem3);
}

sem_close(sem1);
sem_close(sem2);
sem_close(sem3);

sem_unlink(SEM_NAME);


/* remove shared memory segment */
//shmctl(segment_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have more issues than just the segfault. Note that there is **nothing** in your code that enforces your highly specific ordering requirement. You need a compare-and-swap operation using modulo arithmetic to compute proper expected reference values... You could try using the semaphore to *wake up* all processes in a refined version of `do { if(check-current-value) {update-to-next-value; wakeup(everyone);} block-on(sem); } while(!done)` flow.

Comment: Sorry if I sound kinda dumb on this matter, this is my first time using semaphores in a program, but wouldn't what you have suggested just create a race condition by waking up all three of the processes at one time?

Comment: @Ramirez77 That's the point of semaphores: multiple processes race to acquire the semaphore, but the semaphore guarantees precisely one will win. The others go back to sleep.

Comment: @Ramirez77 In particular in this case you should note that the structure of the flow, plus the ordering requirement implies that always at most 1 of the childs makes forwards progress (we only do something if the conditions are right, and we only wake up everyone after making progress).

Comment: I did manage to fix the segmentation faults I had by changing the initialization of the semaphores by doing. sem1 = sem_open(SEM_NAME, O_CREAT, 0664, 1) instead. I guess I should ask, in this situation is it required to have 3 semaphores or is it possible with fewer?

Comment: In the posted code, there is actually only one semaphore.  if you want 3 semaphores, then there needs to be three unique names (and the leading '/' is necessary in most OSs) and each semaphore needs to be unlinked

Comment: the processing of the returned value from fork() is not correct.  the returned value can be <0 (when a error occurs) =0 (when executing from the child) >0 when executing from the parent).   The code needs to properly handle each of those conditions

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my program so it works properly, I created two more SEM_NAME definitions and used those to store sem2 and sem3. I changed the while loops to do while loops, and removed most of the sem_post calls and it works properly now.